# How can I listen to Screen Rotations in React Native, including e.g. a rotation from landscape-left to landscape-right?

Tags: react-native, device-orientation

I am writing a React Native app (iOS only at the moment) and I want to do something whenever the screen orientation changes, where the orientations that I care about are:

- Landscape-left
- Portrait
- Landscape-right
- Portrait-upside-down

With the built-in Dimensions api, I can listen to changes in the screen dimensions like this:

```
import {Dimensions} from "react-native"

const dimensionListener = Dimensions.addEventListener("change", () => {
    // Do great things
})
```

But if I flip my device from landscape-left to landscape-right, this does not trigger, because the dimensions (height/width) have not changed.

Is there another way, e.g. to listen to any "rotation" event at all?

I've seen [react-native-orientation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-orientation) and [react-native-orientation-locker](https://github.com/wonday/react-native-orientation-locker) and it seems like they may be outdated/buggy.  A more "native" solution would be great.

Comment: react-native-orientation-locker is probably your best bet, to build this out yourself with a native bridge would be a huge amount of work, react-native-orientation-locker is kept up to date and works with the latest RN version.